# files indexing automatically by elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a newbie in elasticsearch, please forgive me if my question sounds weird :D
I want to index files in some directories with elasticsearch automatically (for example: if i add a file in certain directory then elasticsearch can index that file immediately), but i don't know how to configure elasticsearch in order to solve that problem.
Can anyone suggest me?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can have elasticsearch watch a directory (I wouldn't think that is a good thing to do in most cases.)

Instead, have a client wrapper that implements a FileWatcher. Push changes to ElasticSearch via this client.

You could use [PathHierarchyTokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) to preserve the file system hierarchy in your index, allowing you to drill down your Directory structure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Srikanth. I will try to implement your suggestion.